# Double floating-point precision in Java

Tags: java

In Java, I've noticed that `1.1+(2.2*(3.3+4.4))` results in `18.040000000000003`, rather than `18.04`. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: for why this doesn't come out exactly, see [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/217324)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the result of using floating point arithmetic, you have two options:

1. `Math.round` the result of that operation, but i guess this is not what you want.
2. Use `java.math.BigDecimal` (arbitrary precision decimals) that allows you to store those decimal without loss of precision.

Comment: Works well enough:) Apparently, I can't accept yet, so that's coming soon (expect it in about 1 hour!)

Comment: This is a precision issue, not a rounding issue

Comment: It's not fixed point arithmetic - it's using `double`, which is floating point.

Comment: @ControlAltDel, correct, that because i gave him two option :)

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right as usual :) , fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal requires precise calculation with full control over the precision, then I would suggest using `BigDecimal` class. BigDecimal allows one to set very precise rules with which the calculations are done by setting the number of digits after the division point, rounding mode and by accepting a [MathContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html) as an argument.

There are however some drawbacks. First off, `BigDecimal`s are objects thus all operations are done via methods, and not using standard math operators. This is a bit cumbersome, especially while building more complex expressions, and if not done carefully might lead to some nasty, unclead code. Secondly, since as was said, all operations are done on objects, they are more heavy resource-wise.